# Закрепить диалог на виджете

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Всем привет. Собственно вопрос заключается вот в чем: можно ли, а если можно, то как закрепить диалог на виджете? Например, мне не нужно вызывать QFileDialog по клику, а нужно чтобы он всегда был на одном виджете (не в отдельном окне).

Comment: Не проверял, но может быть сработает dlg.setParent(mainWnd);? Разумеется, нужно будет указать расположение на форме, размеры, видимость.

Comment: @maestro Благодарю за помощь. Пробовал так сделать. Вопрос решил. Только странно. Если родителем является MainWindow, то ничего не происходит, но если это ui->CentralWidget, то диалог появляется без всяких проблем.